# Sequelize define model via json schema

Tags: javascript, json, schema, sequelize.js

I want to make the Sequelize model ad through json. I can not find in the documentation whether it is possible to make a model declaration via the json schema. For such a strong library it is strange that there is no such function. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Do you mean JSON file? like read schema from JSON file and create model?

Comment: that's exactly what I mean. generateModel(jsonSchema) => .....  return sequelizeModel

Comment: JSON only has string, number, boolean, JSON object, and null as datatype. Therefore it is not suitable to be used as Sequelize model schema. Though I am sure you can still hack it to work, it is not a good idea at all

Comment: It is faster to write implementation myself)

Comment: "For such a strong library it is strange that there is no such function. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place"

--> When it comes to Sequelize, SO **is** the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Just tried to find answer for same question.

schema xample

> {   "type": "object",   "$schema":
>   "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",   "id":
>   "http://api.example.com/v1/schemas/user",   "properties": {
>       "active": {
>         "type": "boolean"
>       },
>       "effectiveDate": {
>         "type": "string",
>         "format": "date-time"
>       },
>       "username": {
>         "type": "string",
>         "maxLength": 255
>       },
>       "password": {
>         "description": "Sets a new password, this is not retrievable.",
>         "type": "string"
>       },
>       "email": {
>         "type": "string",
>         "format": "email"
>       },
>       "role": {
>         "type": "string",
>         "enum": [ "admin", "staff", "guest" ]
>       },
>       "tags": {
>         "type": "array",
>         "items": {
>           "type": "string"
>         }
>       },
>       "homeAddress": { "$ref": "http://api.example.com/v1/schemas/address" },
>       "billingAddress": { "$ref": "http://api.example.com/v1/schemas/address" }   } }

usage xample

```
const jsonSchemas = [
  require('./schemas/address.schema.json'),
  require('./schemas/user.schema.json'),
];

const definition = Sequelizer.fromJsonSchema(jsonSchemas, 'http://api.example.com/v1/schemas/user', {
  uniqueFields: ['username'],
  mixinFields: ['homeAddress', 'billingAddress'],
  customFieldDefinitions: {
    passwordHash: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    password: {
      type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
      set(val) {
        this.setDataValue('password_hash', val + '_salt');
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Library location [github/ronalddddd/sequelizer](https://github.com/ronalddddd/sequelizer)